# Get the date/time a badge was awarded?

Tags: r, stackexchange-api

Using this, it is possible to take the badges from a specific user of Stack Overflow:

```
library(stackr) 
badges <- stack_users(9371451, "badges", num_pages=100000, pagesize=100)
```

How can I add a parameter to take also the timestamp that the badge was awarded to the user? And if possible, for which answer?

Comment: Looking at the Stack Exchange API docs, <https://api.stackexchange.com/docs>, it looks like the timestamp is not available through the API.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `users/{ids}/timeline`. See [description page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/timeline-on-users):

> Returns a subset of the actions the users in {ids} have taken on the site.
>
> This method returns users' posts, edits, and earned badges in the order they were accomplished.

```
library(stackr)
df_timeline <- stackr:::stack_GET("users/9371451/timeline", num_pages = 10000)
```

The `:::` is necessary because the function `stack_GET` is an internal command

Answer (score 1):

It is possible-*ish* with the Stack Exchange API, but not with [the *stackr* library](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr) you are using.

The [`/users/{ids}/badges` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-on-users) returns a list of [badge objects](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/badge), which only has these *possible* properties:

```
    award_count     integer
    badge_id        integer, refers to a badge
    badge_type      one of named, or tag_based
    description     string 
    link            string 
    name            string
    rank            one of gold, silver, or bronze
    user            shallow_user
```

So you can't get the timestamp or triggering post there.

However, you *can* get this information (mostly) from [the `/notifications` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/notifications), which can return results like:

```js
{ "items": [ {
      "site": {"site_url": "https://webmasters.stackexchange.com"},
      "is_unread": false,
      "creation_date": 1520234766,
      "notification_type": "badge_earned",
      "body":   `You've earned the \"Notable Question\" badge for 
                <a href=\"http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65822\">
                How to bulk delete email accounts from cPanel / my hosting account?</a>.`
                //  Manually wrapped for this post
    },
    etc.
```

But, **important:**

1. `/notifications` **requires authentication** and only works for a logged-in (via the API) user.
2. That ***stackr* library does not support authentication**. (See your previous question in a bit.)
3. /notifications **returns all of a given user's Stack Exchange sites**, so you will have to filter out the ones you are not interested in.
4. /notifications **returns several kinds of notices**, so you will have to filter out the ones that are not badge related.
5. /notifications does not return badge details like `rank`, so **you will still need to call `/users/{ids}/badges` and marry the results.**
6. For higher rep users, it is possible that you would **exhaust your API quota** before being able to fetch all of that user's notifications.