# How to get the Timestamp of awarded time for badges?

Tags: stackexchange-api, dataexplorer

Which is the way to take the time of a badge awarded to a user?

I tried the notification as it is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49117614/9706864) but I get:

```
method not available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49117614/331508) and [the API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/), **you cannot directly get the badge award times from the API.**
To get them indirectly requires a fair bit of work, which is already summarized in that answer and which you did not do.  Also, the indirect method is limited to a single, logged-in, user per app session.

Perhaps a better approach is to use the Data Explorer (SEDE).

**Here is a query to get a user's badge award times**.
See it in action at SEDE: [data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/851077/...](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/851077/badges-with-award-times-for-a-given-user?UserId=9706864)

```sql
-- UserId: User ID     "Enter a user's ID."
SELECT      u.Id     AS [User Link]
            , CASE
                WHEN b.Tagbased = 1 THEN 'Tag: [' + b.Name + ']'
                ELSE b.Name
            END    AS [Badge name]
            , CASE
                WHEN b.Class = 1 THEN 'Gold'
                WHEN b.Class = 2 THEN 'Silver'
                WHEN b.Class = 3 THEN 'Bronze'
                ELSE '*Unkown*'
            END    AS [Class]
            , b.Date AS [Awarded]
FROM        Badges b
LEFT JOIN   Users u  ON u.Id = b.Userid
WHERE       b.Userid = ##UserId:int##
ORDER  BY   u.Displayname
            , [Awarded] DESC
```

It returns results like:

```
User Link   Badge name        Class      Awarded
Lenak       "Editor"          "Bronze"   "2018-05-02 10:04:38"
Lenak       "Custodian"       "Bronze"   "2018-05-02 09:49:36"
Lenak       "Peer Pressure"   "Bronze"   "2018-04-26 22:18:46"
Lenak       "Informed"        "Bronze"   "2018-04-26 20:38:26"
```